# How can I extend ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging to output json lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

What is the simplest way to use an existing TaggedLogging and update it so it will output json format ?

```
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))
```

Now I would like to have a json output per logger line.
Any idea what is the best approach?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?